# python start_new_thread is printing None

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from _thread import *
def worker():
print("this is a new thread")

start_new_thread(worker, ())
```

In the above python code  it is printing none ,and i dont know why this happens

Comment: there is a tab space before print

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting your def and print function on the same line like this:

```
from _thread import *
def worker(): print("this is a new thread")

start_new_thread(worker, ())
```

Which output

```
18756
this is a new thread
```

Comment: What version of python are you using? Which IDE? I'm running Python 3.7 in VS Code